# Sqlite Query can't get 100%

Tags: sqlite

```
public Cursor getStatsPercent(String startdate, String enddate) {
      String query = "SELECT *, ROUND((count(sex)*100)/(SELECT count(sex) FROM salesTable)) AS '"+PERCENTAGE+"'   FROM salesTable  where timeStamp BETWEEN '"+startdate+"' AND '"+enddate+"'   GROUP BY sex ORDER BY percentage DESC" ;



        Cursor c = dbSales.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Everything works fine but i always get back a Value under 100%.
I think it has to do with the ROUND but couldn't fix this.

Comment: Why round anyway? You use `int` values. So the calculation's result is `int` too

Comment: I have tried it without still the same.

Comment: I bet there is a big stupid mistake that i just can't see. I have three different values in the sex column. (Male, Female, unknown) every row in the sales table has its own "sex" value. I want to get the percentage of that value. For example: salesTable has 30% Female, 60% Male and 10% unknown. But i always get a value under 100% back (like 30%, 60%, 9%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Cursor getStatsPercent(String startdate, String enddate) {
  String query = "SELECT *, ROUND((count(sex)*100.0)/(SELECT count(sex) FROM salesTable)) AS '"+PERCENTAGE+"'   FROM salesTable  where timeStamp BETWEEN '"+startdate+"' AND '"+enddate+"'   GROUP BY sex ORDER BY percentage DESC" ;



    Cursor c = dbSales.rawQuery(query, null);
if (c != null) {
    c.moveToFirst();
}
return c;
```

}

I fixed it, just changed *100 to *100.0
So if anyone wants to calculate the percentage of the values from the database between dates this code should work.